# Best practices: How to use CI/CD to deploy flask webapp to digital ocean?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I am teaching myself how to use Jenkins and Docker for CI/CD and deployment to digital ocean. I am stuck at some steps and I am especially interested in the best practices of CI/CD.

The process/pipeline I currently have:

1. Local code with Flask web app and docker-compose.yml (incl. dockerfile)
2. Push the code to github
3. CI: Local jenkins (will be transferred to the host later in time) tests code
4. If tests run successfully, I log to droplet, clone the repo, stop running docker container, do `docker-compose up`
5. My app is live again

I would like to automate step 4, and potentially I have two plans how to do it (advice on best practice is appreciated!).

**Plan 1:**
 1. Write a step in Jenkins pipeline that will
 4.1. start a new droplet automatically
 4.2 log in into it  with ssh
 4.3 pull code from github
 4.4 start with docker-compose
 4.5 reroute with IP floating to a new droplet

**Plan 2:**
 2. Write a step in Jenkins pipeline that will
4.1 build code and push somehow an image to "somewhere"
4.2 start a new droplet
4.3 log into droplet with ssh
4.4 pull image from "somewhere"
4.5 start with docker-compose
4.6 reroute with IP floating to a new droplet

**I'd like to hear your opinions on the steps:**
1. Which plan is better?
2. What I could do better?
3. What are the best practices that I could use?
4. Where can I push an image so that I can pull it in a new droplet?

EDIT:

**I'd like to hear your answers on following:**
1. Which plan is better?
2. Why is Kubernetes better then docker-compose in production env?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Kubernetes instead of docker-compose on production environments. If not Kubernetes and you really want Docker only then at least make it Docker Swarm..

- docker-compose is not reliable for production because first of all it is only for single node. If you want to scale-up you will surely have downtime because you will be relying on vertical scale (Increasing your node resources).
- Kubernetes and Docker Swarm are orchestration tools. Meaning you can add more servers to scale app a.k.a Horizontal Scaling. This orchestration allows your containers to be assigned to other droplets and they can freely communicate to other containers even if they are in different droplets. **docker-compose** alone can not do that. I will recommend Docker Swarm for beginners as Kubernetes is very complicated

Normally you should just only setup your infrastructure in the cloud then your CI/CD will do the **continuous integration** on Jenkins doing continuous image builds for at least then doing an automated deployment to your server.

- What I am talking about here is.. When you merge your code in a particular branch(**e.g. master**) of your source code repository like Github or Bitbucket then an automatic Jenkins build will run then execute your CI/CD.. So basically everytime master has an update then it will also update your image inside droplet thus having the latest source code

In your case where you are using Digital Ocean.. You can create an API on your droplet for accepting webhooks to trigger the automated deployment

- This is the approach that I can think of when using Digital Ocean. DIgital Ocean is very cheap but things are done manually unlike if you tried GCP and AWS. In GCP and AWS there are more approach to do deployment automation than create your own webhook API. Regarding your last statement **"if I can use Jenkins to clone the code, and run the container in the new droplet and reroute with IP floating"** but I think it is too much and this is slow. This may take maybe 10 minutes whole on this process alone? We do deployment automation w/ our Kubernetes for maybe 30 seconds only. Our whole CI/CD only takes 2 minutes

On your fourth question.. Dockerhub should be fine for your image repository

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have several follow-up questions. 
1. Why Kubernetes instead of docker-compose on production env? And why Docker Swarm?
2. I am not sure what problem you are addressing with your second paragraph. I have Jenkins running locally because I just wanted to test how it works and will deploy it to server. Everything will be in the cloud after I finish the project.
3. Why do I need to create an API on my droplet if I can use Jenkins to clone the code, and run the container in the new droplet and reroute with IP floating?

Comment: Looks like you are a beginner on the CI/CD. I had the same questions before.. I will update my answer please wait

Comment: I updated my answer. Feel free to check